# Using a png as a button in Android studio

Tags: android, button, png

I would like to use a png as a button in android studio. I tried adding the png into the drawable folder in my android project folder, however, when I open my android studio under res there is only one drawable folder with 4 launcher.png and no matter how i try to copy my png in there (over windows folder or directly over android studio) it doesn't work and won't show up. Furthermore, how do I use the png as a button in the xml layout?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the name of your file

Comment: Could you post your screenshot in a link?

Comment: name is smiley.png and unfortunately i cant post screenshots yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the drawable folder, right click, select import and navigate to the png directory, select the .png file.  If that doesn't work, then there is something wrong with your project or eclipse.

As for using it as a button, google has plenty of examples.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thank you, I am using Android Studio, so I selected optimize imports and then it shows you the folder path. I copied the png in there and hit run after clicking optimize imports now it's there

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio, so I selected optimize imports and then it shows you the folder path. I copied the png in there and hit run after clicking optimize imports now it's there .